# How can you improve hair thickness from previous iron deficiency?

Tags: nutrition, dermatology, hairloss

If you are suffering from hair loss from a iron deficiency, are taking an iron dietary supplement for a couple of months and used a topical lotion  so the hair loss stopped how do you retrieve hair thickness?

Comment: Hi, your post is asking for personal medical advice which is not allowed on this site, because we do not have the resources to answer them. Consulting a doctor would be the best course of action for you. I am going to try to edit your question so that it is no longer asking personal medical advice. If you dislike the edits you can always roll-back or edit the question again. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Don't use chemical products use natural products . Take medical advice not online . A doctor can tell you which natural oils or shampoos you can use depending on you skin type .

Comment: Hi and welcome to Health SE! Thank you for your post, however post here generally have links and sources to support them. Adding this would allow you to follow site guidelines. For any other questions ask here or consult the help center. Thank you :)

Comment: @Pobrecita can you tell me how to provide link ?

Comment: On the technical side, you just put the link name in square brackets and next to it, without spaces, the link address in small brackets. You can find more technical details if you click the question mark at the top right corner when you are composing an answer, and then by clicking [advanced help](http://health.stackexchange.com/editing-help). On the content side, you can find some useful sources in: [What are reliable sources](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources). More on site policies at the [help]. Welcome to health SE :-)

Comment: You're welcome, but commercial websites are usually not considered reliable. Do check out the link on reliable resources I gave you, it will give you an idea. You can also browse around [meta](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/) to see some other topics about the functioning of the site. Thanks!

Comment: You say not to take advice online and then post a link to an online medical advice site. Sorry, but your answer looks a lot like spam. I'm editing to remove the link.

Answer (score -3):

**Hair is Protein.**

(and not only micronutrients)

Not only muscles but also hair, and nails require sufficient amout of protein for healthy growth.

I'd consult you to take an overall Vitamin/Mineral pill once a day (the ones that have everything known as vitamins and minerals inside to be sure you have sufficient micro nutrients  ----- but as well keep good care of your protein intake! You may use any source of extra protein like powders or take amino acid - pills. <-- theese guys rock.

> Intake should be about 1,1 gram protein powder per kg bodymass.

Advantage of the amino acid - pills is: Your body doesn't net to detoxify the cellcore dna which is left in the protein powder. In the amino - acid pills - it isnt :)

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Since health is an important topic, we [strongly encourage](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) reliable references to back up all answers, because they are the only way in which the community can assess an answer's merit regardless of the reader's background. You can always [edit] your answer to add references. For more information on site policies please visit the [help] and meta. Thanks!

Comment: Pray tell, what is "cellcore dna" and why does it need to be detoxified? And how would protein supplements help with an iron deficiency? Your response raises more questions than answers.